# Exponential distribution with failure rate

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution

An electric component is known to have a length of life defined by an exponential density with failure rate $10^{-7}$ failures per hour. Determine the fraction of those components that will fail before the mean or expected life?
Can you please help me, how should I answer this?

Answer (score 3):

For *any* exponential distribution, the fraction of components failing in less than the mean lifetime is the same,$$\int_0^{1/\lambda}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=1-\frac1e.$$For what it's worth, $\lambda$ is simply the mean failure rate.

Comment: Very interesting tidbit of information. Though the math is entirely clear, it's still feels odd that for any exponential distribution whatsoever ~63% of components are expected to fail before the *expected* time to failure.

Comment: @RTF Why? _Expectation_ is just a word. Regardless of what _expect_ means in English, the only guarantee the mathematical definition of _expectation_ gives us is that it's a mean, not a median or any other specific quantile.